# Emulate mysql workbench TCP/IP over SSH in ODBC connector

Tags: odbc, mysql-connector

I set up a remote SSH connection with Putty to a mysql datebase using a socket file and port 5001 (required by the provider). With mysql workbench I use the TCP/IP over SSH connection which works fine. Now I require to setup an ODBC connection using the mysql ODBC connector. Using just the setup with localhost/5001 and the dbuser/dbname results in a error 10061 can not connect to mySQL server.
What I am missing is how to setup this ODBC connection with the SSH parameters host, port and SSH username - similar as this is done in the mysql workbench. Is this at all possible in mysql connector?